# How are flipflops with SR, RS, S'R', Qn Qn' in both order equivalent to each other?

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All images link:

https://imgur.com/a/feKDXzd

I want to understand the various variations of above and be able to draw any of the above circuits if I know how to draw one of them.

- latch (using NAND/NOR gates)
- flipflops(using various input combinations)

What's the best way?

**For example, the expected goal for me is to be able to draw any version of flipflops based on just remembering the diagram of SR latch. I want to be able to convert any design to another design.**

So, starting with remembering the truth table is not perhaps the best idea. I want to do at much as small amount of memorization possible.

One concept that I already know is of active high and active low and the concept of bubbled inputs and outputs and NAND and NOR gate as universal gates. Example: AND gate is equal to bubbled NOR gate. And so on.

But that didn't take me too far. Any thing that I might be missing?

[On RS Latches (or Flip-Flops), NOR or NAND, via Duality Principle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/299670/on-rs-latches-or-flip-flops-nor-or-nand-via-duality-principle)

This is the closest post that somehow tries to answer my question in stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

For drawings, the following might work (but the important thing is to know the truth tables):
[image]

Summary tables of the characteristic equations of Flip-Flops:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Anti-bounce circuit:
[image]

Comment: Hey. Where's my asynchronous clear and preset for my master slave JK? My favorite 7476 IC type? I don't see it up there... ;)

Comment: Do you miss the J-K Master-Slave with asynchronous inputs?

Comment: According to the site rules you need to cite the source of these diagrams.

Comment: @RoyC  All designed by me with Paint!!!

Comment: Wow they look really pro!

Comment: @Franc No, I don't miss them. I have a nice box of 7476's that I can take to bed with me and hug at night for security in the knowledge that the world is right and good so long as they are there. ;) (Designed and built my first CPU with them playing key roles. So they have been good to me. ;)

Comment: @ periblepsis Sorry, but you didn't catch the joking tone of my previous reply.

Comment: @Franc I was also having fun joking about it. All is good.